# jQuery Loop through a team list, and also get name and insert into DOM during looping

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

In a view of MVC project, I want to display the name of each player. Player are associated to a team through the team ID, and I am looping through the team on the list, and displaying player's profileID, and other fields.

foreach in a table in the view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ListPlayers)
{
   <tr>
        <td>@item.TeamID</td>
        <td>
            <div class="profileID" id="profileID">
                <a href="/Profile/@item.ProfileID" class="list-group-item">@item.ProfileID</a>
                <div class="nameSection" id="nameSection">
                    <h6>Name:</h6>
                    <div id="nameDisplay"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>@item.Weight</td>
        <td>@item.Jersey</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Using jQuery .each function, I am looping through profileID in the DOM, and calling a getNameDetail function. My jQuery script is as follow:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".nameSection").hide();
        var profID;

        $('.profileID').each(function () {
            profID = $('a', this).text();
            getNameDetail();
            $('#nameSection').show().insertAfter(this);

            function getNameDetail() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/profile/GetNameByProfileID/" + profID,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { profileID: profID },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $("#nameDisplay").empty().append(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("name detail was populated error");
                    }

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I am pulling profileID correctly, and the data from getNameDetail is also correct. But not going into #nameSection part correctly. i.e. something wrong with my

```
 $('#nameSection').show().insertAfter(this);
```

The result I am trying to display:

profileID:12345
         Name: firstname1 lastname1

profileID:12359
         Name: firstname2 lastname2

etc.

Would someone please help?

Comment: yes, the alert(data) popup window showed correct name information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your output is from above, but I'm guessing that the issue is because your `nameSection` is no unique, when your ajax call returns with some data, jquery will do the search on the document for the `nameSection` id, and randomly pick one to assign the data to.  I think the solution would be to make the `nameSection` id unique for each block, or, like you have done with the text selection from the anchor tag, use the this as the context for your selection or the `nameSection` elements.  You would want to assign the `this` variable to `that` first, so that the ajax function can reference it.  So the solution could be 1)

```
<div class="nameSection" id="nameSection">
...
<div id="nameDisplay"></div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="nameSection" id="nameSection@item.ProfileID">
...
<div id="nameDisplay@item.ProfileID"></div>
```

(just stick the id on the end of each id), then in the each block, this

```
$('#nameSection').show().insertAfter(this);
....
$("#nameDisplay").empty().append(data);
```

becomes

```
$('#nameSection'+profID).show().insertAfter(this);
...
$("#nameDisplay"+profID).empty().append(data);
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for your reply. I think your guessing "randomly pick one to assign the data to" is correct. Looks like attaching profileID to id is the way to go. But code <div class="nameSection" id="nameSection@item.ProfileID">
...
<div id="nameDisplay@item.ProfileID"></div> is not working...i.e. not attaching the profileID to nameSection or nameDisplay. Would you help?

Comment: Does the Id get attached to the URL for the anchor tag?

Comment: yes, the anchor tag works fine. In anchor tag, the intellisense is working while I am typing @item.ProfileID, but with id="nameSection@item.ProfileID", the intellisense is not coming with the .ProfileID. Thining I am lacking a big knowledge of html...

Comment: Mmm, that doesn't make any sense. If the I'd is being written out correctly in the href, there is no reason that it shouldn't be written out correctly after those other two ids...the I'd will still be in scope at that point.

Comment: Rob, would you please take a look of the new code I posted? For some reason, I have to have   alert(profID); first, and then profID = $('a', this).text(); the result displays correctly for all data. If I delete alert(profID); then none names are populated. If I put alert(profID) after profID = $('a', this).text();, then the names are populated off by one record, i.e. the first one has empty name, the second ProfileID takes the first name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes according to your suggestions. The "nameSection" id is only using the profileID, so the foreach loop to populate the table is like:

```
   @foreach (var item in Model.ListPlayers)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>@item.TeamID</td>
            <td>
                <div class="profileID" id="profileID">
                    <a href="/Profile/@item.ProfileID" class="list-group-item">@item.ProfileID</a>
                    <div class="nameSection" id="@item.ProfileID">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>@item.Weight</td>
            <td>@item.Jersey</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

and the jQuery is as follow:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var profID;

        $('.profileID').each(function () {
            alert(profID);
            profID = $('a', this).text();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/profile/GetNameByProfileID/" + profID,
                type: 'POST',
                data: { profileID: profID },
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#" + profID).empty().append(data);
                    $("#" + profID).show();

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("name detail was populated error");
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works fine with the alert(profID) inside the each function. If I delete the alert(profID), then nameSections are "no show". I couldn't figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

the reason the alert will be making the code work is that it will be slowing things down.  The ajax call will be happening asynchronously,but with the alert in there, it will give the call time to happen and return the results.  Why the values are not being set on the nameSections, I'm guessing, will be because the `profID` is outside of the `each` function.  At normal speed (without the alerts), the for loop will zip through, changing the profID each time.  Then at some point, the ajax calls will start returning their results, long after the profID has changed.

With the code that you have there, can we comment out the `var profID;` outside of the `each` and add `var` infront of the `profID` inside the `each` loop?

Comment: here are some fiddles of what I'm trying to explain, I've simulated the ajax call with a time out.  This is the current version replicating what you have: //jsfiddle.net/8eeo0xqq/ and this is the corrected version where the profId has been scoped to each item in the each loop : http://jsfiddle.net/rwjwilson/z6zs7ncu/

Comment: Rob: your suggestion worked like a charm. The names are nicely populated. I checked against my sql database, and the data are all correct! Thank you so much for your help and great explanation!

Comment: awesome, I'm really glad :)